# Check that two arrays in json have the same size

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

Can I somehow validate that two arrays in one json have the same size using json schema? May be there is some way to use variable for maxItems and minItems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this with JSON Schema.  This would require reading data from one part of the instance and using that to validate another part of the instance.  There *is* a [lot of discussion](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3A%24data) around this, but the team has been focused on other requested features lately.

I would suggest that you simply check the length of the arrays.  You don't mention what system/language you're using, but I'm sure that your local JSON library should be able to give you that info pretty simply.

Comment: Bump. Since the accepted answer was given nearly 5 years ago and referenced ongoing discussion, has there been any change to JSON in that time that allows writing a schema to require that two arrays be of the same (but otherwise arbitrary) length?

Comment: There might be a way. Let me play with an idea, and I'll be back to edit my answer.

Comment: No, sorry.  There's still not a way to do this.  I was thinking maybe you could use my [data vocab extension](https://docs.json-everything.net/schema/vocabs/data-2023/), but it can only capture the data itself; there's not a way to capture information _about_ the data.